# Ext.form.Panel is not correctly calculates dirty on consume record if lookup was used before

Tags: extjs, extjs7, formpanel

I'm trying to bind to form's dirty property
but, looks like it is processed incorrectly

Please, check fiddle for code example and a description for the bug

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ovk

```
// define model
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'age',   type: 'int', convert: null},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'alive', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true, convert: null}
    ],
});
 
// create new record, some filed should have empty string (ex. phone)
var user = Ext.create('User', {
    id   : 'ABCD12345',
    name : 'Conan',
    age  : 123,
    phone: ''
    // phone: '123456789' // if the field is not empty, then dirty updated correctly
});
 
// create basic form
// (viewModel and binding just to check form dirty property)
var form = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    viewModel: true,
    reference: 'formref',
    publishes: ["dirty"],
    trackResetOnLoad: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'id',
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'name',
            name: 'name'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'age',
            name: 'age'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'phone',
            name: 'phone',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            bubbleDirty: false,
            bind: '{formref.dirty}'
        },
    ]
});
 
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
 
    launch : function() {
        // render container and lookup for something to reproduce form durty bug
        var container = Ext.create({
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [form]
        })
        Ext.Viewport.add(container);
 
        // comment next line to check formref.dirty is set correctly
        var f = container.lookup('formref');
 
        // lookup will call
        // beginSyncChildDirty: function() {
        //     this._childDirtyState = { counter: 0, ready: false };
        // },
        // so, it initialize counter
        // as phone field value is not changed, it will call adjustChildDirtyCount with false
        // childDirtyState.counter += dirty ? 1 : -1;
        // now, the childDirtyState.counter is equal to -1
        // and !!childDirtyState.counter equal to true
        // me.setDirty(!!childDirtyState.counter);
        // formref.dirty is now set to true
 
        form.setRecord(user);
    }
});
```

Key to reproduce - call lookup() before setting record to the form panel

I'm looking for the correct fix of the issue

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was discussing the issue with Sencha Support team, and we came up with a quick fix for the issue by adding an override:

```js
    Ext.override(Ext.form.Panel, {
        adjustChildDirtyCount: function (dirty) {
            var me = this,
                childDirtyState = me._childDirtyState;
            if (childDirtyState) {

                if (childDirtyState.ready) {
                    childDirtyState.counter += dirty ? 1 : -1;
                    // Fix - Counter should not be less than 0
                    if(childDirtyState.counter < 0){
                        childDirtyState.counter = 0
                    }
                    me.setDirty(!!childDirtyState.counter);
                } else if (dirty) {
                    childDirtyState.ready = true
                    ++childDirtyState.counter;
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Looks like it works for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in you current code, `lookup` does not even find your form panel. Check this by adding `console.log(f);` after `var f = container.lookup...`. It will log `null`.

This can be easily fixed by adding the `referenceHolder: true,` configuration to the `container`. After this it will already find the form panel within the container.

As for your question, my guess it is some kind of a race condition. The `launch` function is called at the very early stage of starting an Ext JS application and the framework might not be completely ready with setting up the components. Usually `lookup` is called from controllers or other places where the initialisation is already completed.

Try to add a button to the form panel and call `lookup` from there, and remove the `lookup` call from the `launch` function.

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Lookup test',
    handler: function (button) {
        var f = button.up('formpanel').up('container').lookup('formref');
        console.log(f);
    }
}],
```

After this you will see that the dirty bind works as expected, even if you press the button, and from the console log you see that the `lookup` finds the form panel.

Complete code with the suggested changes:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'age',
        type: 'int',
        convert: null
    }, {
        name: 'phone',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'alive',
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultValue: true,
        convert: null
    }],
});

var user = Ext.create('User', {
    id: 'ABCD12345',
    name: 'Conan',
    age: 123,
    phone: ''
});

var form = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    viewModel: true,
    reference: 'formref',
    publishes: ["dirty"],
    trackResetOnLoad: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        label: 'id',
        name: 'id'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        label: 'name',
        name: 'name'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        label: 'age',
        name: 'age'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        label: 'phone',
        name: 'phone',
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        bubbleDirty: false,
        bind: '{formref.dirty}'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Lookup',
        handler: function (button) {
            var f = button.up('formpanel').up('container').lookup('formref');
            console.log(f);
        }
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        var container = Ext.create({
            referenceHolder: true,
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [form]
        })
        Ext.Viewport.add(container);
        form.setRecord(user);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter!
yeah, it wasn't a goal to actually find a component with `lookup`, so, it doesn't matter in this case. The problem is `lookup` method is calling `beginSyncChildDirty` and this breaks dirty calculation process.. Putting `lookup` into a button handler is not actually the fix, it's just a different case.